# Checkbox expands another checkboxes when checked not working reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, radio-button

I have a mapping function which shows JSON values into checkboxes, I'm tried to add the children of these values as checkboxes under the current checkboxes, and it worked fine, but what I am trying to do now is make the show the 2 children checkbox once the parent checkbox is clicked.

I have Side Collection 1 and under it there are children (side 1 and side 2), what I tried but couldn't do is show (side 1 and side 2 checkboxes) once (Side Collection 1 checkbox) is checked, the checkbox values are passed as props from **Checkbox.js** to **Itemlist.js** where the fetch/map happens. Would Appreciate it if anyone can explain or demonstrate how this can be achieved.

I have done a the function i want in vanillajs but im not sure how to add it to my react app specially that is within a mapping function, im new to react

Function snippet: https://codepen.io/alaafm/pen/eXGZbO?editors=1010

React Live Snippet: https://codesandbox.io/embed/5w8vwwmn5p?fontsize=14

**Checkbox.js**

```
 class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
          <div className="inputGroup">
            <input
              id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
              name="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.childk + this.props.name}>
              {this.props.name}{" "}
            </label>
          </div>{" "}
          {this.props.options &&
            this.props.options.map(item => {
              return (
                <div className="inputGroup2">
                  {" "}
                  <div className="inputGroup">
                    <input
                      id={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
                      name="checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                    />
                    <label
                      htmlFor={
                        this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
                      }
                    >
                      {item.name || item.description}{" "}
                      {/** <img src={this.props.img} alt="" /> <span className="pricemod">{props.childprice} SAR</span>
                       */}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

**Itemlist.js**

```
...
  <div>
            {selectedMod &&
              selectedMod.children &&
              selectedMod.children.map((item, index) => (
                <Checkboxes
                  key={index}
                  name={item.name || item.description}
                  myKey={index}
                  options={item.children}
                  childk={item.id}
                  limit={item.max}
                />
              ))}
          </div>  
...
```

**JS Function** which i want to add

```
  const myCheck2 = document.getElementById("check2");
  const dib = document.getElementById("dib");
function change() {
  if (myCheck2.checked) {
      dib.style.display = "block";
          dib2.style.display = "block";

  }
  else{
    dib.style.display = "none";
    dib2.style.display = "none";
   }
}
function func2() {
  if (this.checked) {
     myCheck2.checked = false;
    dib.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    dib.style.display = "block";
    myCheck2.checked = true;
  }
}

myCheck2.addEventListener('click', change);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use internal state in Checkboxes.js and conditional rendering to show sub-checkboxes.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Checkbox.css";

class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
  }

  render() {

    const input2Checkboxes = this.props.options &&
      this.props.options.map(item => {
        return (
          <div className="inputGroup2">
            {" "}
            <div className="inputGroup">
              <input
                id={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
                name="checkbox"
                type="checkbox"
              />
              <label
                htmlFor={
                  this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
                }
              >
                {item.name || item.description}{" "}
                {/** <img src={this.props.img} alt="" /> <span className="pricemod">{props.childprice} SAR</span>
                       */}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })

    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
          <div className="inputGroup">
            <input
              id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
              name="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={() => {
                this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.childk + this.props.name}>
              {this.props.name}{" "}
            </label>
          </div>{" "}
          {this.state.checked ? input2Checkboxes : undefined }


        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of react component state and for your `checkbox.js` component. If state changes, then the component will re-render with the correct checkboxes.

I would suggest having a state with a boolean to know if the slide collection checkbox is selected or not, and have the onChange function of your parent checkbox input look something like this:

```
<input
    id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
    name="checkbox"
    type="checkbox"
    onChange={()=> this.setState({parentCheckbox:!this.state.parentCheckbox})}
/>
```

Then in your method where you map through this.props.options to render the children checkboxes, you can have a conditional statement for just the input tag that will have it render only if `this.state.parentCheckbox` is true - see the method below.

```js
render() {
    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
          <div className="inputGroup">
            <input
              id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
              name="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={()=> this.setState({parentCheckbox:!this.state.parentCheckbox})}
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.childk + this.props.name}>
              {this.props.name}{" "}
            </label>
          </div>{" "}
          {this.props.options &&
            this.props.options.map(item => {
              return (
                <div className="inputGroup2">
                  {" "}
                  <div className="inputGroup">
                    { this.state.parentCheckbox && (<input
                      id={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
                      name="checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                    />)}
                    <label
                      htmlFor={
                        this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
                      }
                    >
                      {item.name || item.description}{" "}
                      {/** <img src={this.props.img} alt="" /> <span className="pricemod">{props.childprice} SAR</span>
                       */}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```